# Function prototype in header files

Tags: c++

I wanted to know what the difference between the following two declarations is in header files
I have come across both these styles

```
void some_method(int);
```

and the second style is :

```
void some_method(int a);
```

Does one style have any benefit over the other. To me one style just does not have the name of a variable and the name of the variable has to be implemented in the accompanying cpp file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference in functionality, but I often use parameter names as a form of documentation, like so:

```
void verbTheThing(int verbId, int thingId);
```

When I have nothing valuable to add, I just don't add it:

```
int max(int, int);
```

Comment: There's a workflow benefit in keeping the declaration and definition the same - you can then easily copy and paste between one and the other - this is not so easy if you use the shorter form for the declaration.

Comment: @PaulR Good point. I might instead have said that I make an effort to remove meaningless (potentially distracting) parameter names when putting the prototype in the header file.

Answer (score 4):

The main concern is **consistency**. Pick one and stick to it. I prefer the second personally because parameter names can describe functionality and code that's self-documenting is better than the alternative.

Comment: +1; I usually make exceptions for defaulted and deleted special functions, though.

Answer (score 3):

The main difference is readability. The second version is longer, but having the name of the argument may be a real help. Little example :

```
int move(int, int, int, int);

int move (int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY);
```

Answer (score 2):

Some development environments (Visual Studio, Borland C++ Builder, for example, eclipse is also supposed to have this feature) automatically list function arguments, when you enter `(` bracket.

[image: list parameters]

For those IDEs it is common courtesy to make sure that function argument names (within headers) are as descriptive as possible, because they serve as documentation.

Even if programmer doesn't have IDE with this feature, forward function declarations (in headers) should always be as descriptive as possible. For the same reason - it is easier to open header and read what function parameters are supposed to mean, instead of hunting for function body within myriad of `*.cpp` files.

Not to mention that in some functions you can't figure out what parameters are supposed to mean without parameter names.

For example,

```
 Image::blitRect(int, int, int, int);
```

could be

```
 Image::blitRect(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2);
 Image::blitRect(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
 Image::blitRect(int x, int y, int width, int height);
```

Of course, a C++ programmer would add classes for Point and Size in this situation, but that's another story.

Answer (score 1):

Both do not ,make any difference as far as the compilation is concerned. But the second one is better, as giving a name to a parameter increases the readability of the code and helps people understand it better

Answer (score 1):

Both options are valid. But specifying the parameter name in header can greatly help someone reading function signature to quickly figure out what it actually does and what data do parameters represent.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no difference between them.
It boils down to where you are declaring your methods...
For example, in case when you declare your function before "main()" func.
you probably do not need to care about parameters name. However, having preceded method 
declaration you have to introduce your parameters name in defintion.
It's just Code Style, enables you and anyone to read you code